# Explanation of Step-$7$ of Baby Rudin chapter-$1$ Appendix constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Just started on baby rudin and im confused on step $7$. In step $6$ the author defines multiplication for positive cuts of the real numbers and in step $7$, he extends it by defining:

$\alpha\beta=(-\alpha)(-\beta)$ if $\alpha,\beta<0^*$

$\alpha\beta=-[(-\alpha)(\beta)]$ if $\alpha<0^*,\beta>0^*$

$\alpha\beta=-[(\alpha)(-\beta)]$ if $\alpha>0^*,\beta<0^*$

After defining these, he claims that repeated application of the identity $\gamma=-(-\gamma)$ allows us to prove that the axioms of multiplication will hold in $\mathbb{R}$ but i don’t see how we will be using the identity to prove this? Wouldn’t the above definition itself be sufficient in making multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ well-defined since we are defining multiplication non-positive cuts to be some multiplication of positive cuts(in all 3 cases) and then taking the additive inverse of that cut if necessary(in the second and third case), both of which is already well-defined, so how would any of these involve the aforementioned identity?

In the next part of step 7, he proves the distributive law by breaking it into multiple cases, for one particular case, i am not sure whether my proof is correct, $\alpha>0$ and $\beta,\gamma<0$. In this case, $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=-[\alpha(-(\beta+\gamma)]$. To proceed we would have to prove that $-(\beta+\gamma)=-\beta-\gamma$. Im not sure if my proof of either is valid, Especially for ==> direction

<== Let $x \in -\beta-\gamma$, then $x = p+q$ such that $-p-r \not\in \beta$ and $-q-k \not\in \gamma$ for some $r,k>0$, then clearly $-x-(r+k) \not\in \beta+\gamma$ and thus $x\in -(\beta+\gamma)$

==> let $x \in -(\beta+\gamma)$, then $-x-r \not\in \beta+\gamma$, let $b$ and $g$ be the sup of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively and let $2d=-x-b-g>0$ then $(b+d)-d/2 \not\in \beta$ and $(g+d)-d/2 \not\in \gamma$, it follows that $-b-d\in -\beta$ and $-g-d\in -\gamma$,  and thus $-b-d-g-d=x \in -\beta -\gamma$.

Sorry if its a bit messy, even rereading what im writing is kind of hard but im not too sure how to better phrase stuff better here, if there’s any part that is needing in clarification, let me know and i will try to rephrase it more sensibly again.